Alternate solution for pairing Snow White and the 7 dwarfs

Snow White and the seven dwarfs are playing a game, and need to be
split into groups of two. Show that
this can be done in exactly 105 ways.

An Exploration of Olympiad Combinatorics - Rushil Mathur, pg 22, Problem 12
My solution:
Let the number of ways of splitting n people into pairs be $a_n$ ( for even n obviously). Let $a_0 =1$.
I thought of the recurrence $a_n = (n-1)a_{n-2}$. Clearly $a_2 = 1$ and $a_4 = 3$. Then, $a_8 = 105$. My question is:
a) How do you prove the recurrence
b) Are there any alternate, simpler ways to solve it?
My thought behind the recurrence:
Snow white may be paired with any of the $(n-1)$ dwarfs. The rest of the pairs are simply the case of $n-2$. Is this statement a valid proof of the recurrence?

Not sure I understand the question.  You are just trying to group ${s_1, \cdots, s_8}$ into pairs?  So, $7$ choices to pair $s_1$ with, then $5$ choices to pair the least non-paired subject, then $3$. And $7\times 5\times 3=105$.   I think it's clear from that how to get a recurrence, right?  Though, I don't really see the advantage.

Your argument for the recurrence seems fine to me.

"a) How do you prove the recurrence" Induction of course.  If $a_n=K$ then $a_{n+2}$ would be.  Pick one player arbitrarily.  There are $(n-1)$ possible partners for that player.  For any of those potential $n-1$ pairings there $n$ remaining players left to pair.  There are $a_n$ ways to do that.  SO there are $a_{n+2}=(n+1)a_n$ ways to pair $n+2$ people.  (I think it's intuitively easier to start with $a_2 =1$ rather than $a_0=1$ but starting with $a_0=1$ is not incorrect.)

"My thought behind the recurrence:
Snow white may be paired with any of the (n−1)
dwarfs. "  my only quibble is you are specifying the $n$th person specifically to be Snow White.  Doesn't that imply when you were calculation $n-2$ that neither snow white nor the $n-1$th dwarf weren't there? But the how can you calculate $a_{n-2}$ if it requires that the $n-2$nd person is Snow White, which we just said it can't be... okay, that's a silly quibble but....

@lulu Oh of course, that escaped my mind, and I could only think of recursion. There was no advantage, it was just the only thing that came to mind

@fleablood Right, that was my idea, I just chose Snow White to represent the arbitrary n-th person, which is quite silly in hindsight

There are $\binom{8}{2}$ different ways of choosing the "first" pair, $\binom{6}{2}$ ways of choosing the "second" pair, $\binom{4}{2}$ ways of choosing the "third" pair, and $\binom{2}{2}$ ways of choosing the "fourth" team.  Hence there are
$$ \binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2} \require{cancel}$$
total ways of assigning the pairs.  However, this overcounts, as the order in which the pairs are chosen doesn't matter (i.e. if Doc and Dopey are assigned to the first pair, that is the same as having Doc and Dopey assigned to the third pair).  There are a total of $4!$ different ways of ordering the pairs, so divide out the redundancies.  The total number of possible pairings is then
\begin{align} {\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}}\frac{1}{4!}
&= \frac{8!}{2!\cancel{6!}} \frac{\cancel{6!}}{2!\cancel{4!}} \frac{\cancel{4!}}{2!\cancel{2!}} \frac{\cancel{2!}}{2!0!} \frac{1}{4!} \\
&= \frac{8!}{(2!)^4 4!} \tag{$\ast$}\label{eq} \\
&= \frac{8!}{4!} \cdot \frac{1}{2^4} \\
&= \frac{\cancel{8}\cdot 7\cdot \cancelto{3}{6} \cdot 5}{\cancel{8}\cdot \cancel{2}} \\
&= 7\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \\
&= 105.
\end{align}
Note that I have written out the final computations as I would do if I had to do this by hand—computers make things a bit easier.
As an addendum, note that this generalizes.  Given $2n$ objects which need to be paired, there are
$$ \prod_{j=1}^{n} \binom{2j}{2} $$
different ways of pairing them up in order.  Since the ordering of the pairs doesn't matter, the $n$ pairs can be permuted, giving $n!$ different redundant permutations of pairs.  So a general formula, similar to that given at (\ref{eq}), is that the number of possible pairs possible with $2n$ objects is
$$ \frac{1}{n!} \prod_{j=1}^{n} \binom{2j}{2} = \frac{(2n)!}{n! 2^n}. $$

(a) The argument for the recurrence is ok
(b) Lulu has already given an alternate way to form pairs. This skipping by two is known as a double factorial,$\quad (n-1)!!$
Another common way to get the # of pairs (here it is simpler to consider n as any positive integer, thus 2n total) is to first permute all 2n people in a line, but since neither their position in the line, nor the position within any pair matters, divide by ${n!2^n}$ to get
Number of  of possible pairs $= \dfrac{(2n)!}{n!2^n}$

I just saw another solution, which said you could do: ${2n} \choose 2$×$  {2n-2} \choose 2$... and then divide by $n!$. Is this essentially your first solution?

We are getting into storytelling here: the solution $k=2n$ and possible ways to make pairs=$\frac{(2n)!}{n!2^n}$ reflects the story: line them in a wall the every even person pairs with the person before them, we have an ordered list of $n$ ordered pairs but the order doesn't matter so divide by the numbers of ways to order the $n$ pairs and the way to order the couples in each pair. The solution ${2n\choose 2}\cdot {2n-1\choose 2}\cdot...$ reflects the story: Put the people in a big room.  Pick two at random, then another two, then another two.....

I'd so the double factorial method (lulu's answer) reflects the story: put the in a room.  Pick a person as random.  There are $2n-1$  possible partners. After partnering that person up there are $2n-2$ people remaining.  Pick one at random.  There are $2n-3$ possible partner.  Partner up and move on.  Number of ways is $(2n-1)(2n-3)(2n-5).... = (2n-1)!$.
